# JavaScript and jQuery Alert find("td:first").html() and Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I am unsure why my getCereal variable id using the find("td:first").html() is not working.  I have been able to create my table, however my click event will not work.  I am stumped.  Any input will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <div id="cer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  // jQuery onClick event
  // the click function MUST BE USED CANNOT BE ALTERED OR REMOVED
  $(function () {
    $("table tr").click(function (event) {
  function getCereal(id) {
  for (var cerId = 0; cerId < cereals.length; cerId++){
    if(cereals[cerId].id == id){
      alert(cereals[cerId].id +" " + cereals[cerId].name + " " + 
   cereals[cerId].like);
      break;
     }
  }
}

var id = $(this).find("td:first").html();
getCereal(id)


// This creates an cereal constructor object
function cereal(id, name, like) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.like = like;
}



// This creates 5 new objects with cereal information.
const cereals = [
  new cereal(1, 'Captain Crunch', 'Yes'),
  new cereal(2, 'Frosted Wheats ', 'Yes'),
  new cereal(3, 'Shredded Wheat', 'No'),
  new cereal(4, 'Trix', 'No'),
  new cereal(5, 'Count Chocula', 'No'),
];

var output = "<h1>Cereal Listing</h1><table><thead>"+"<tr>"+"<th>"+"Id"+"</th>"+"<th>"+"Cereal Name"+"</th>"+"<th>"+"Like?"+"</th>"+"</tr>"+"</thead>"
for (var x = 0; x < cereals.length; x++) {
    output +='<tr>' + "<td>" +  cereals[x].id + "</td>"  +"<td>" + cereals[x].name + "</td>" + "<td>"  + cereals[x].like +"</td>" + '</a>' + "</tr>";
}
output += "</table>";
document.getElementById('cer').innerHTML = output;

})
  });
</script>
```

Comment: start by cleaning up your string composing.

`"</th>"+"<th>"` serves no purpose over `"</th><th>"`, you only need to add strings together when dealing with a variable, like `"<td>" + cereals[x].name + "</td>"`

Comment: Your code example has comments that aren't commented out. Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: Should I be using the th when creating a header>

Comment: your `table` > `tr` > `th` looks fine to me

Comment: I am stuck user on executing the correct event when registering the onClick event.  I do not know what to execute to get the row information using the getCereal function to iterate the row.  I have never even heard of the  find('td:first').html() function.

Comment: `'<tr"<href="#" class="tabletr">` is definitely wrong. and you're also closing an anchor tag outside your td

Comment: you should read up on jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: I did read that, however it did not seem to help me with the id:first.html() function.  I apologize, I am new to this so I am working through this to try and get me on the right path.

Comment: jquery is a selector language, it selects for you a dom element. The return from the selector `$('td:first')` ( notice I use `$` not `find` ) will return the first td dom node it finds. on the whole page. Then, running `.html()` returns all the html contents of that node as a string.

Comment: Ok I think I understand that, however if you can help me understand how I would use that to search for an id that I click on and alert that using the function.  I am very new and am not sure how to move forward.  Thank you so much for your assistance you have really shed some light on the td:first.  I really did not understand that one at all.

Comment: add a click handler on the thing you want to click, then check `e.currentTarget` in the event handler to find the what was clicked on. You can also use jQuery here, `$(e.currentTarget)`. From there you can grab it's value and continue with your code.

Comment: Ok I did some research on that.  I think I understand that, however wont that override my click function?

Comment: you don't 'override' anything in js, it's not a thing.
if you add another click event listener, you just have two now.

Comment: Ok I see.  Just curious, why can't I get the table to show when I have the click function showing and not commented out?  That is really confusing to me, don't I need to utilize that function some how?  I am so sorry for the elementary questions.  I am very new to JavaScript and jQuery.  I am trying so hard to get this done and I am so appreciative of your assistance.

Comment: because there is no table to click on.

Comment: open up google console and try the jquery selectors there.

Comment: @binarie you've defined a function inside a callback, so it will not execute. Also you have called a function that is not defined: `getEmployee`

Comment: Sorry that is supposed to be getCereal I have edited  sorry about that I am piecing things together as I go.  I am VERY new to this so I really appreciate your assistance.  I did some googleing, however I am not sure what you mean when you say a defined a function inside of a callback.  I am so sorry I am a total newbie and I still learning.  I am taking a class, however it is not helping me much with this one.  I am even close to getting something working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really unclear what the goal is here. Maybe this will help, consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  function cereal(id, name, like) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.like = like;
  }

  const cereals = [
    new cereal(1, 'Captain Crunch', 'Yes'),
    new cereal(2, 'Frosted Wheats ', 'Yes'),
    new cereal(3, 'Shredded Wheat', 'No'),
    new cereal(4, 'Trix', 'No'),
    new cereal(5, 'Count Chocula', 'No'),
  ];

  var output = "<h1>Cereal Listing</h1>";
  output += "<table class='cereal-table'><thead>";
  output += "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Cereal Name</th><th>Like?</th></tr>";
  output += "</thead><tbody>";
  $.each(cereals, function(k, c) {
    var row = $("<tr>", {
      "data-c-id": k
    });
    $("<td>").html(c.id).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html(c.name).appendTo(row);
    $("<td>").html(c.like).appendTo(row);
    output += row.prop("outerHTML");
  });
  output += "</tbody></table>";

  $("#cer").html(output);
  $(".cereal-table").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
    var cId = parseInt($(this).data("c-id"));
    console.log("Row C-ID: " + cId);
    var data = "";
    data += "ID: " + cereals[cId].id;
    data += ", Name: " + cereals[cId].name;
    data += ", Like: " + cereals[cId].like
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cer"></div>
```

Since jQuery is a JavaScript Framework, you can mix and match both, yet I try to remain in one or the other. This is all in jQuery.

The function creates an Object. You have 5 objects in an Array and we're going to iterate the Array using `$.each()`. This is a functioned designed for this. See: 
[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Each Object has parameters we can call and insert into the Table Cell elements `<td>`. jQuery give us the ability to quickly create elements as jQuery Objects: `$("<td>")`.

Since the goal appears to be to create an `output` string of HTML text, we can convert all the jQuery Objects we've create into HTML by asking for the `outerHTML` property.

The result of running the code is:

```
<h1>Cereal Listing</h1><table><thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Cereal Name</th><th>Like?</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Captain Crunch</td><td>Yes</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Frosted Wheats </td><td>Yes</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Shredded Wheat</td><td>No</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Trix</td><td>No</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Count Chocula</td><td>No</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Once the table is constructed and outputted, you can bind a `click` event to the Row with `.on()` or `.click()`. I advise the `.on()` since it more tolerate of dynamic content.

We bind the `click` event to each row and then collect the data from the row and create an alert.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I am sorry for the confusion.  I need to create the table using jQuery and click on the row to output which will alert the row.  I believe that I have something started based on my code, however it still will not work.  See edits

Comment: When you say *will alert the row*, I don't know what that means.

Comment: Hi Twisty.  I have edited my original post, however the intention is to send an alert when a user clicks on the row.  The intention is to alert with all of the data in the row regardless of where they click.  I have edited my original post and added some new code.  Let me know if this makes makes any sense.  The only thing is that I have to use  find("td:first").html(); and the function   $(function () {
    $("table tr").click(function (event) {
  function getCereal(id) { cannot be altered.

Comment: @binarie revamped to make use of Array Index versus data in the table. Same result, different method.